# Highcharts series , linkedto more than one series

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I want to use the linkedTo option in my series in order to link several series to each other. For instance if I have series with ids: series1, series2, series3, series4, I want to link all of them together expect series2.

What is the syntax of `linkedTo: ...` ?

I tried using array, like below but it didn't work:

`{
 id:'series1',
 linkedTo: ['series3','series4'],
 data : ...
},
...`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way for doing this instead of giving an array to the `linkedTo` option:

you could give `linkedTo: null` for the first series and give `linkedTo: 'series1'` for the other series. (link all to the first series)

Also use `showInLegend: true` for the first series and `showInLegend: false` for the rest.

Example:

`{
 id:'series1',
 linkedTo: null,
 showLegened: true
 data : ...
 },
 {
 id:'series3',
 linkedTo: 'series1',
 showLegened: false
 data : ...
 },
...`